# Different ways to declare a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

What's the difference between:

```
let data = [String:Any]()
let data = Dictionary<String, Any>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same thing to declare and initialize an empty dictionary of that key and value type.

Apple documents the first way in their [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html).  (Scroll down to Dictionaries section).

The second way you show is simply more formal, which may help those new to Swift who don’t know the dictionary shorthand/literal syntax.

The